# No resource found that matches the given name iys tag me to color?

Tags: android, xml, gradle, android-support-library

Hi Guys in my project faced me problem

> Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

if I click **jump to sources**

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <resources>
>     <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored"
> parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored"/>
>     <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Colored" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored"/>
>     <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Info.Media"/>
>     <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Media"/>
>     <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Time.Media"/>
>     <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Title.Media"/> </resources>
```

my gradle File is

build.gradle(Module:AppName) `

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:24'
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nileworx.flagsquiz"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 24
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':baseGameUtils')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
}
```

build.gradle(Module:baseGameUtils)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
 compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:24'
 buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'

 defaultConfig {
     minSdkVersion 11
     targetSdkVersion 24
 }

 buildTypes {
     release {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
     }
 } }

dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+' }
```

by the way its game so if anyone solved please put it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the image below

[image]

`android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored` requires API level 24

You can bump everything to 24 to follow your support library as below or to the latest version and it will fix the problem, but be aware that your minSDK is 11 and it means that the style won't applied in older versions

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.nileworx.flagsquiz"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 24
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
  } 
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile project(':baseGameUtils')

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.4.0' 
}
```

Comment: i just install API24 ?? Error:failed to find target with hash string 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:24' in: C:\Users\Mrwan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>

Comment: can you update your post with your latest gradle file?

Comment: also in Android Studio, try going to Tool > SDK Manager > SDK Platform > Check the option "Show Package Detal > APi Level 24 and check if Android SDK Platform is installed

Comment: replace `'Google Inc.:Google APIs:24'` to just `24`. It should fix it

Comment: new Error Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1
<a href="add.google.maven.repository">Add Google Maven repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:C:/Users/Mrwan/Desktop/codecanyon-20941183-flags-quiz-android-game/Flags_Quiz_Android_Game/Flags_Quiz_AS/flagsQuiz/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Comment: that's because you increased your support library to `27.1.1` drop it to `24.0.0` or increase your compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, and targetSdkVersion to `27`

Answer (score 0):

When I pasted your code into mine there were a lot of formatting issues, maybe you just had wrong formatting in your file. 
Try that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored" />
<style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Colored" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored" />
<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Info.Media" />
<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Media" />
<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Time.Media" />
<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Title.Media" /> </resources>
```

Comment: the project was Eclipse

Comment: by the way this xml code in file ' v24\values-v24.xml '